# My android SDK isn't working with the chaquopy how to fix this?

Tags: python, java, android-studio, chaquopy

Hi so I've succesfully added chaquppy to my android project, however I have the problem that everytime I sync my project withthe python files, the app tells me that no Android SDK is defined. So I go ahead and sync it with the gradle files, then there is an SDK defined, but I have to resync it with the python files, and then there is again no Android SDK defined.
I am completely confused about what to do now, because somehow nothing works.

After syncing with the gradle files

[image]

After syncing with the python files

[image]

I tried as described syncing with the gradle files and then again with the python files and it didn't work.
I even set up a completely fresh project, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Your images don't show the actual Gradle error message. If you still need help, please edit your question to include the error message, which should be in the Build window (View > Tool Windows > Build). Then post a comment below.